# Meaning of php , when parsing a json

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have seen that after url for example

Please help me tu understand this, i have tried to find somewhere else but nothing

What does" php?later_word=" mean, and how to do that

Comment: You'll have to add more details/code to turn this post in a valid question.

Comment: GET parameters, do you know them? Read it up.

Comment: For example: www.lidero.com/ende/app.php?later_word=

Comment: And what does this  "app.php?later_word=" mean

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php
Btw. this have nothing to do with json or java.
In your example later_word would be one of this GET parameter you can acces with PHP. They can contain any value you give them and you can access them in your code for future use.

Comment: `app.php` is the php file name and `?later_word=` is the GET Parameter

Comment: I am new at this and i dont know nothing, im learning and i want to know how can i do the same, thanks a lot for your hel0

Comment: Thank you very mutch, i appreciate your help, how to mark this question answered

Answer (score 0):

So, you wan't to do the same as you said in the comment section on your first post.

So here a short resume how you can use GET paremter. Lets say, you have a index.html file. Create a link in it, for example:

```
<a href="yourdomain.com/filename.php?key=AnythingYouWant">Click here</a>
```

So, in your filename.php you can do:

```
<?php
$yourvalue = $_GET["key"];
?>
```

So, this means you can acces this key from the url with $_GET. In this example, $yourvalue would contain "AnythingYouWant". So if you would do the following:

```
<?php
$yourvalue = $_GET["key"];
echo "Here is your $yourvalue";
?>
```

The output would be:
Here is your AnythingYouWant.

This is useful because PHP variables are not saved when you click on a link for example.

But dude, we posted you a link to the official description... normally you would find this answer by yourself. I really recommend you to read more tutorials, this are the basics of basics.

Answer (score 0):

I know this can seem overwhelming, so I'll give you some pointers on which parts of internet basics you seem to be unclear about:

1. URLs. Find out what a URL is, what it is made of (scheme, path/suffix, domain name, query, port, and also the optional username/password in URLs might be good things to know about).
2. HTTP requests and in particular HTTP "methods". The most common you need to know are GET and POST, but there are many others, and you should have a basic understanding so you know how to look up a new one.
3. Web servers (i.e. HTTP servers, which at their most basic show static files of a web page). Usually people use Apache or NGinx as servers
4. Scripting languages to run scripts when someone sends a request to a web server. Examples are Python, Ruby, Perl and, in your case, PHP.

All of these work together to present a modern web site that shows more than just static text and pictures. #1 in that list is something you already need to know as an advanced user of any web browser, understanding 2 and 3 kind of goes hand-in-hand with making even simple web sites of your own, and once you understand that, you can advance to one of the languages mentioned in #4 to make a web site that can do something with user input.